# MsiGetSummaryInformation always returns invalid parameter error

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to set the [Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372070(v=VS.85).aspx) property in the Summary Information Stram but whatever I do, it fails. I can read the property from the handle but can't write it back.

I want to generate multilingual copies of the MSI which is built (candled and light) in English. I am able to replace all the respective translated data in all the tables; the only thing I can not change is the Template property above.

I have tried all the ways I can use to pass the new String value, but it always says invalid parameter.
Here's the function I am using to do the same (C#):

```
public Boolean ChangeTemplateSummaryProperty(String strLangID) {
IntPtr hSIHandle;
if (MsiError.Success == MsiInterop.MsiGetSummaryInformation(IntPtr.Zero, m_strMSIPath, 1, out hSIHandle))
{
    VariantType vtType = VariantType.LPStr;
    int iVal = 0;
    FILETIME oFileTime;
    oFileTime.HighDateTime = 0;
    oFileTime.LowDateTime = 0;

    int iValSz = 0;
    MsiError err = MsiInterop.MsiSummaryInfoGetProperty(hSIHandle, (uint)(SummaryInformationStreamProperty.Template),
                            out vtType, out iVal, out oFileTime, String.Empty, ref iValSz);
    String strValue = new String('l', ++iValSz);

    if (err == MsiError.MoreData)
    {
        err = MsiInterop.MsiSummaryInfoGetProperty(hSIHandle, (uint)(SummaryInformationStreamProperty.Template),
                                out vtType, out iVal, out oFileTime, strValue, ref iValSz);

    }
    else
    {
        Logger.LogError("Failed to get SummaryInformationStreamProperty.Template... err = " + err);
    }
    //I get the correct value here. as ";1033\0"
    Logger.LogInfo("SummaryInformationStreamProperty.Template: " + strValue);

    char[] arrNV = new char[strLangID.Length+2];
    arrNV[0] = ';';
    for (int i = 1; i < strLangID.Length + 1; i++) {
        arrNV[i] = strLangID[i-1];
    }
    arrNV[strLangID.Length+1] = '\0';
    String strNewVal = new String(arrNV);

    //tried this, but fails.
    //string strNV = ";";
    //string strNV2 = strNV.Insert(1, strLangID);
    //strNV2 = strNV2.Insert(strLangID.Length + 1, "\0");

    err = MsiInterop.MsiSummaryInfoSetProperty(hSIHandle, (uint)(SummaryInformationStreamProperty.Template),
                                vtType, iVal, oFileTime, strNewVal);
    if (err != MsiError.NoError)
    {
        Logger.LogError("Failed to set SummaryInformationStreamProperty.Template... err = " + err);
        MsiInterop.MsiSummaryInfoPersist(hSIHandle);
        MsiInterop.MsiCloseHandle(hSIHandle);
        return false;
    }
    MsiInterop.MsiSummaryInfoPersist(hSIHandle);
    MsiInterop.MsiCloseHandle(hSIHandle);
}
else
{
    Logger.LogError("Failed to MsiGetSummaryInformation...");
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the MsiInterop that you are using and use the interop found in WiX's DTF.  The Microsoft.Deploymnet.WindowsInstaller namespace has a SummaryInformation Class that exposes a read/write string Template property.  Way better object model and interop without worrying about all the P/Invoke details that your current interop makes you deal with.

I'm home now so here's a code snippet:

```
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using( var database = new Database(@"C:\orca.msi", DatabaseOpenMode.Direct  ))
            {
                database.SummaryInfo.Template = "Intel;666";
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the use of the using() clause.  The Database class implements the IDisposable interface and automatically handles ( pun intended ) cleaning up all those pesky unmanaged handles for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Christopher,
But I am not able to import the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller; package. It will be helpful if elaborate more on this like, Which reference I am supposed to add to get this package?
I have C# express edition installed and using .NET framework 2.0 for the application. Is this info helpful?
Thanks
Rahul Muley.

Comment: You tagged this question with WiX so I'm assuming you have WiX installed.   If not goto wix.codeplex.com and download the release 3.0.   You'll find your reference in ProgramFilesFolder\Windows Installer XML\SDK\bin

Answer (score 0):

```
Database msidb = objInstaller.OpenDatabase(MSIFileNameWithPath,MsiOpenDatabaseMode.msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact);
SummaryInfo info = msidb.get_SummaryInformation(1);
info.set_Property(2, (object)("sample title"));
info.Persist();
msidb.Commit();
```

The best reference to answer this is in detail is

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mwade/sail-away-with-me-to-another-world